# Exibir imagens de um campo BLOB de um banco firebird em PHP

Tags: php, firebird, blob

Acho que alguém vai se sentir no direito de falar que esta pergunta é uma duplicada, mas eu discordo, não tem uma pergunta que responda de forma simples e objetiva um método de exibir uma imagem de um campo *blob* em *PHP*, usando *Firebird*.

Pelo que consegui reunir na internet. Este código parece correto.

```
if($db = ibase_connect('C:\Banco.FDB', 'sysdba', 'masterkey')){
    $result = ibase_query($db, 'SELECT IMAGEM FROM PRODUTO_GALERIA where id = 478');
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($result)) {
       header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
       echo $row->IMAGEM;
    }
    }
```

Uma simples consulta em uma das minhas tabelas que traz uma imagem como resultado (com o id 478), porém o resultado não é uma imagem e sim um quadrado pequeno no meio da tela. Tentei todos métodos que eu achei na internet e só consegui erros de compilação e esse quadradinho na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Removendo o `header`, aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Já testou com outros dados?

Comment: Que eu me lembre quando remove o header aparece um.codigo hexadecimal e eu testei todas as imagens e dá o mesmo resultado